# Get customer groupname in shipping magento

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.9, magento-1.9.1

how to get the customer group in magento admin shipping page?

i can not get order instance in magento shipping page from admin side. i want to get the customer group, in other pages this code is working fine. for example in sales/order/invoice/create/items/renderer/default.phtml

```
<?php $_order = $this->getOrder();
$customerId = $_order->getCustomerId();
$customer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->load($customerId);
$customer_group =  $customer['group_id'];
$customer_role = Mage::getSingleton('customer/group')->load($customer_group)->getData('customer_group_code');
$role   = strtolower($customer_role);
?>
```

based on role i am doing some display conditions in this page.
but in this page i am not getting user role.app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/sales/order/shipment/create/items/renderer/default.phtml page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of $_order = $this->getOrder(); this i have used below code, Now i am getting the order instance.

```
$_order = Mage::getModel('sales/order');
```